# Need help creating an Excel formula involving dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of 18 varied dates which as they pass, I need to know how many of the 18 dates are left. Can I do this with an excel formula?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Example:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A18,">"&TODAY())
```